# How can I enable mouse control in vim of homebrew?

Tags: vim, homebrew

I want to enable mouse control on vim.
In terminal.app on OS X, it supporting `mouse reporting`. (El capitan or later)
I using vim of homebrew, there is no build option to enable mouse control in it vim.

How I can enable it?

Comment: I just built vim in homebrew with no special options, and `+mouse_xterm` is active. Is yours building without mouse support? You can run `:version` to see the feature list in your build of vim.

Comment: thanks for comment!  
I don't confirmed that homebrew vim enable mouse by default or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a option for it.

```
:set mouse=a
```

will allow you to scroll through the screen. 
You can put this in ~/.vimrc file.

To disable it, you can `:set mouse=r` or `:set mouse=n`.